# Kafka Source JDBC Connector - Micro-batching

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

As part of a POC, I have a Kafka JDBC Source Connector task which basically reads all the contents of a MySQL table and dumps the records into a Kafka topic.

The table contains 2 records only & my batch.max.rows value is 2. When the task runs on "bulk" mode, I see 2 individual JSON records in the kafka topic. How would I configure the connector to insert 1 JSON record which contains a JSON array containing those 2 records. Ultimately the no. of messages published to kafka topic to be 1 instead of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each database row will become a unique Kafka record.

If you want to join / window records, then you would use a Stream Processor

Comment: Thanks.. Yeah realized that would be simpler.